# Mocha with Selenium, how to use the browser in all cases?

Tags: javascript, selenium, typescript, mocha.js, chai

I am still trying to get this thing up and running and my current problem is that I can't use the same browser in all my test cases. For example:

```
describe('Check the website', function() {
    var driver: Driver = new Driver();

it('Check website title', function() {
    this.timeout(0);

    driver.Firefox.get("http://google.com");
    driver.Firefox.getTitle().then(function(title){
        expect(title).to.equal('Google');
    });
});

it('Second test', function() {
    this.timeout(0);

    driver.Firefox.get("http://google.bg");
    driver.Firefox.getTitle().then(function(title) {
        expect(title).to.equal('Google24');
    });
    });
});
```

I want to use the same browser across all tests, how do I do that?

If I put `var driver: Driver = new Driver();` inside the test cases everything works fine, the problem is that after it completes with the first test it closes the browser and then it opens it again for the second test, and this costs a lot of time.

P.S. Driver is a class that I made for initializing my browser I want to make it usable across the whole project, I am using TypeScript, but I guess that I would have the same problem in JS, how to use the same variable across all test cases?

Answer (score -1):

> I want to use the same browser across all tests, how do I do that?

**Don't** do this.. this is bad test design.

*Why?*  It's common practice for automated testing to start with a fresh instance each test.  Test dependency is generally frowned upon.  Consider the following:

```
TestSuite
  TestCase1
  TestCase2
  TestCase3
  TestCase4
```

Say `TestCase2` fails.. now `3` and `4` will fail.

Starting browsers are cheap, and you should consider the idempotence and maintainability before you share browsers.

Comment: For example: I want to have a test that checks the page title, a test that checks if a few elements are available, a test that checks something else (all on the same webpage) and these tests can use the same browser. I dont think that I should start 3 browsers just to check 3 things on the same webpage.

for example:
describe("Check if all login form elements are present" ....
 it("Is X element present")
 it("Is the title correct")
 it("Is some other thing present")
and so on

Comment: well then those aren't test "cases", those are test "steps."  you can have multiple steps (checks)  sure.

Comment: Back to my original question, how do I use the browser across all these steps? Check my code, is this the correct way to do it?